# Removing text from main page

Tags: 7

In the main page I've got text "The front page". I managed to change that text but unfortunately I don't rembember appropriate place.

How can I remove that text?

Comment: Any screenshot plz?

Answer (score 0):

"Find Content" (/admin/content) then Edit the node.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: OP didn't remember where to edit node text, so I gave them the url of the admin page in question and instructed which link to select. How does that not answer the question?